# NodeJs MongoDb Result without getters and setters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, d3.js

I`m developing a NodeJs application that utilizes MongoDB to store large sets of data. The data is retrieved using the “.find” or the “.findOne” query functions.

```
const collection = db.collection('recordings');

collection.find({}, {fields: ['header']}).toArray()
    .then(documents => {
        console.log(documents);
        resolve(documents);
    })
    .catch(error => reject(error));
```

The application is build using Electron Js, so I’m able to inspect the data via the chrome developer tools:

[image: The console ouput]
Having these getters and setters makes the application pretty slow. Since the data is also visualised in a D3-Chart i came up with this rather odd solution to remove all functions:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(documents))
```

Without this extra step the charts starts to stutter.

Is there a better way to retrieve the raw results without cycling through all the documents to remove the unnecessary getter and setter functions?

Thank you.

Comment: Not overly familiar with `mongodb` but I just tried to replicate your problem.  I don't get these `get` and `set` methods in my return, just a flat array of objects.  What version of node mongodb client are you using?  I tried with 2.2.11...

Answer (score 2):

Problem definately not in mongo. Im also confuced with this line `{fields: ['header']}`.

If you want just header field you need to query like this

`collection.find({}, {'header': 1, _id: 0}).toArray()`.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The style of projection I used is just a different syntax. I have changed it according to the official documentation.
The strange "getter" and "setter" problem ist still there. Maybe this only occurs because I use Mongo DB in the Electron renderer process.

Comment: Could be. Because i never seen this kind of issue in mongo. Btw what modules you using to connect and query mongodb?

Comment: Its just the plain mongodb node module:  "mongodb": "^2.2.11"

Comment: Hm..then it's definately electron. It somehow add getters and setters for all data in array. You need to look how disable this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after following the recommendations of this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38490959/1292336

The problem only occurs if you connect the Electron renderer process directly to the mongo database.
You should use the main process and transfer the result of each query using ipc.

Thanks to Mykola Borysyuk and Marc for reconstructing the issue :)

Comment: Np.Glat that helped you.

Comment: That's still strange.  My test was done in the "render" process.  I just `<script>` directly in my `index.html`.  Glad you go it sorted though.

Comment: Did you require the mongodb package directly from the renderer process or via require('electron').remote('mongodb')?
The thing is that I need do use a second renderer process, so the other window and the main process can still operate while the data gets aggregated.