# Can we use mongodb with node js to build desktop apps in electron js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I wanna know can we use mongodb with electron.js to build offline apps. Let’s say an app To-Do. As electron uses node. I know we can use mongodb to build web app. But I want to know if I can build desktop app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i use mongodb with electron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479607/how-do-i-use-mongodb-with-electron)

Comment: No I am just a beginner. I couldn’t get that.

Comment: Recommend to use sqlite3 as your DB. There are some issues to package the mongodb while you are building as production.

Comment: You can run mongo server as a service and, from your mainprocess, write services toaccess the mongodb , just like a node app